# How to get the kernel version name from downloaded Ubuntu ISO

Tags: kernel, iso

Say I have downloaded Ubuntu ISO from the official website of Ubuntu: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

I have downloaded a file `focal-desktop-amd64.iso` and the extracted contents of this ISO file are

> [image: screenshot]

I am not able to get similar files like in installed Ubuntu 19.10, I have these files

```
/boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-26-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-26-generic
```

Is there a way to get these file names from the Downloaded ISO without installing it on the system?

Comment: Another way is to visit http://www.cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/focal-desktop-amd64.manifest which lists linux-generic 5.4.0.9.11, 
linux-headers-5.4.0-9 5.4.0-9.12, 
linux-headers-5.4.0-9-generic 5.4.0-9.12, 
linux-headers-generic 5.4.0.9.11, 
linux-image-5.4.0-9-generic 5.4.0-9.12, 
linux-image-generic 5.4.0.9.11

Comment: Please explain what you try to do and why. -- It may work but it may also cause big problems, if you use a linux kernel that belongs to another version of Ubuntu.

Comment: So you have the answer in your question. Ubuntu 19.10 ISO has `5.3.0-26-generic` kernel.

Comment: @Pilot6 that's an example for the Q... 19.10 is installed and thus I know those names.. I have asked for any other downloaded Ubuntu ISO from 0fficial site.. Without Installing on the system..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You can loop mount first the iso file and then the squashfs file:**

Create mountpoints

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/lp1
sudo mkdir /mnt/lp2
```

Mount

```
sudo mount -o loop focal-desktop-amd64.iso /mnt/lp1
sudo mount -o loop /mnt/lp1/casper/filesystem.squashfs /mnt/lp2
```

Check for the kernel version

```
$ sudo find /mnt/lp2 -name "linux-image-[0-9.-]*-generic"
/mnt/lp2/usr/share/doc/linux-image-5.4.0-9-generic
```

My focal iso file was not downloaded today, you may find a newer kernel version.

Please note that there are several files, that belong to the kernel.

**Edit:**

Thanks for the heads up @Jags, I will add, that if you want to check for the kernel version in the newest versions of Ubuntu Server, for example in Mantiq (to be released as 23.10), there are 4 squashfs files, and you should use the following command line,

```
sudo mount -o loop mantic-live-server-amd64.iso /mnt/lp1
sudo mount -o loop /mnt/lp1/casper/ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.generic.squashfs /mnt/lp2
```

2023-09-26 I found `linux-image-6.5.0-5-generic`,

```
$ sudo find /mnt/lp2 -name "linux-image-[0-9.-]*-generic"
/mnt/lp2/usr/share/doc/linux-image-6.5.0-5-generic
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/txDml.png perfect.. thats nice from you `admin@i7-4770:~$ sudo find /mnt/lp2 -name "linux-image-[0-9.-]*-generic"
[sudo] password for admin: 
/mnt/lp2/usr/share/doc/linux-image-5.3.0-24-generic
admin@i7-4770:~$ `

Comment: @YuganTej, I'm glad that I could help :-) sudodus is my username - a palindrome made from `sudo`.

Comment: I have tested it with my previous install of 18.04 ISO.. Perfect result https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fraB.png

Comment: And then: `$ cat /mnt/lp2/etc/lsb-release`. That will tell you what release you have.

Comment: hi @sudodus Just in case, if anyone come across looking up for `Ubuntu Server`, as of Ubuntu 23.04, for `mantic-live-server-amd64.iso`, replace: `/mnt/lp1/casper/filesystem.squashfs` with: `/mnt/lp1/casper/ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.generic.squashfs`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Double click the `.iso` and then double click `/casper/filesystem.squashf` by opening the mounted `.iso` in a file manager window.

To verify that `archive mounter` (NOT `manager`!) can do this, right click each of the files and see that `archive mounter` is a viable option, perhaps subordinate to the "open with" suggestions.

The  `.iso` file structure has been available since at least 2012 (Ubuntu 12.04) and the `.squashf` file structure sometime before 2018 (Ubuntu 18.04).

Flavours of Ubuntu, such as Xubuntu 18.04, cannot do this but then even more fundamental file/volume/disk functionality is lacking such as `gparted, disk-utility (palimpsest)`, etc.

Then open a terminal window (ctr) ... to be completed