# Is there any way to see what kernel version originally Ubuntu has been released without installing the image?

Tags: kernel, updates, versions

Currently Ubuntu 22.04 server has been released in April 21, 2022. Now there is an update: Ubuntu 22.04.1. I would like to know if there is a way or website for checking the original/exact kernel version name for those Ubuntu releases?

I know downloading the Ubuntu image and install it will solve my issue. However I need to take the image created at work. In this case I do not know whether they have updated the kernel or not.

I am looking something like CentOS has for each version.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS

In that website, you will find tables and the kernel version for each version. I want something similar for Ubuntu. What I want to know if the complete kernel version and not only the 5.15 baseline (for example I would like to see that name 5.15.0.25-generic for each Ubuntu release).

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but every Ubuntu ISO has a manifest file available with it, which tells you the version number of every package enclosed within that ISO; ie. versions of all packages including kernels.  You can view package versions via https://packages.ubuntu.com/ or even launchpad.net  (fyi:  on my own box; if I want to look at package versions I use CLI tools like `rmadison` as most questions here are for different releases than my own; but it shows latest versions, not versions on initial media (original version) you seem to seek)

Comment: Thank you @guiverc that I was looking for. I just search in the latest Ubuntu server image and I found the kernel version used for that release. For example in latest Ubuntu 22.04.1, the version is: linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic_5.15.0-43.46 as **5.15.0-43-generic** kernel version.

Comment: If you have the iso file, you need not create a USB boot drive and/or boot it. You can loop mount the iso file and then the squashfs file and look for a kernel file according to [my answer at this link to another AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204557/how-to-get-the-kernel-version-name-from-downloaded-ubuntu-iso)